# Necessary files not showing up on github for android project

Tags: java, android-studio, github

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dX2Zq.png)

I'm new to android studio. Every time I share a new project on github, some of the necessary files and folders (settings.gradle, gradle/wrapper and .idea folder, gradlew, gradlew.properties,gradlew.bat) needed for someone to clone my project are not showing up on github, making it impossible for me to be graded remotely as a student.

The only files showing up are the app folder, the .gitignore, build.gradle, and gradle.properties files only.

Please help!

Comment: Your .gitignore looks fine. Could you perhaps elaborate and how you actually push to Git? Are you using the CLI or the IDE? And could you post the output of `git status`?

Comment: First i synced the project files with gradle using the elephant icon, then I enabled version control using the vcs option in IDE, and chose the default Git vcs. The rest of the process of pushing to github I used the CLI, (gitinit, git remote-add... git add-commit, git push...)

Comment: On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: That's all the git status outputs

Comment: Could you perhaps execute `git check-ignore --verbose gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar` to see what exactly is causing the Gradle Wrapper to be ignored for example?

Comment: This was the reply:" /home/njoki254/.gitignore_global:43:gradle      gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar"

Comment: So this is the problem as mentioned in my answer below. You have the gradle wrapper in your global .gitignore. Just delete the line mentioning it and the others for settings.gradle and so on and you should be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find out why certain files like the gradle wrapper are ignored by using `git check-ignore --verbose gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar`.

Afterwards, you just need to adjust the relevant config file and remove the arbitrary lines. In your case (as I can see from your last comment on the original question), the `.gitignore` file in your user directory is the problem.